# Script MSSQL query on remote server

Tags: sql-server

I have a bit of an odd requirement to script some MSSQL queries on a remote host.

I need to be able to run these queries via an Enterprise Scheduler, in this case TIDAL 6.1, and save the output of the query as a CSV or XML file.

I'm assuming I would have to set up a local SQL server to act as a bridge to the remote host, and I'm hoping there is a way to tell the script/query to output the results as a file on the local host.

Comment: I don't understand the issue.  Can't you just create a stored procedure on the remote server and execute that from the scheduler?  Alternatively, can you link from a local machine to the remote one and create and schedule the stored procedure there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have SQL Client in the machine where you will be running this query. You can run the SQLCMD command below to run the query and save output to file.

sqlcmd -S(servername) -E -i(sql file) -o(output filename) -d(databasename) -s,

-E option is for trusted connection

Hope this helps.